# TiKz: Coloring a node partially

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to partially color a node, like a gradient but in some specific parts. For example the first 50% as black then the other 25% as black!80 then the next 12.5% black!60, and goes on, in an arbitrary amount of sub parts, in this case always using half of space of previous one, like a infinite sum of $\frac{1}{2^n}$ something like the figure

[image]

Also, it should be nice to arbitraly pick the colors, like red, blue, green, yellow, magenta, brown, etc. something like

[image]

Is that doable? If so, how?

PS: This was made on GIMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but it is easier without nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
    \clip (0.5,0.5) circle[radius=0.5];
    \foreach \i/\c in {0/100,1/80,2/60,3/40,4/20,5/10} {
        \fill[black!\c] ({1-1/pow(2,\i)},0) rectangle (1,1);
    }
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-1.5cm]
    \clip (0.5,0.5) circle[radius=0.5];
    \foreach \i/\c in {0/red,1/blue,2/green,3/yellow,4/magenta,5/brown} {
        \fill[\c] ({1-1/pow(2,\i)},0) rectangle (1,1);
    }
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you still want to have nodes filled with this pattern, you can make use of `path picture`s:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    gray steps/.style={
        path picture={
            \foreach \i/\c in {0/100,1/80,2/60,3/40,4/20,5/10} {
                \fill[black!\c] 
                    let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.east)-(path picture bounding box.west)$) in
                    ([xshift={(1-1/pow(2,\i))*\x1}]path picture bounding box.south west)
                    rectangle 
                    (path picture bounding box.north east);
            }
        }
    },
    colorful steps/.style={
        path picture={
            \foreach \i/\c in {0/red,1/blue,2/green,3/yellow,4/magenta,5/brown} {
                \fill[\c] 
                    let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.east)-(path picture bounding box.west)$) in
                    ([xshift={(1-1/pow(2,\i))*\x1}]path picture bounding box.south west)
                    rectangle 
                    (path picture bounding box.north east);
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[gray steps, circle, text width=1cm] at (0,0) {};

\node[colorful steps, circle, text width=1cm] at (0,-1.5) {};

\node[colorful steps, text width=1cm] at (0,-2.5) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need multiple nodes and the pattern is always the same, except for the colors and their number, you can generalise the above as:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    colorful steps/.style={
        path picture={
            \foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in {#1} {
                \fill[\c] 
                    let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.east)-(path picture bounding box.west)$) in
                    ([xshift={(1-1/pow(2,\i))*\x1}]path picture bounding box.south west)
                    rectangle 
                    (path picture bounding box.north east);
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[colorful steps={red,blue}, circle, text width=1cm] at (0,0) {};

\node[colorful steps={red,blue,green,yellow,magenta,brown}, circle, text width=1cm] at (0,-1.5) {};

\node[colorful steps={black, black!80, black!60}, circle, text width=1cm] at (0,-3) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, at least I think that as nodes, since will be used in a graph with many nodes and I would like to color it in each step with a progressive amount of gradients. It will represent the amount of information that each node receives from a dataflow. (is to illustrate a Recurrent Neural Network). The ideia is the first node with a single color, the second node with 2 colors, the third node with three colors and goes on. I will normally stop on 5th node otherwise the colors start to be unreadable. That is just to show the intuition. I have seen a RNN colored like that, just cannot recall where.

Comment: @Lin Ok, I am not sure if I understood correclty what you want to achieve. I added another solution where you essentially only provide the colors you want the node to be filled with. You can choose as many colors as you want.